# Hide a script from a mobile browser

Tags: mobile

I'm trying to hide a script from running when a mobile devise is detected.

I have tried a similar answer that was on another post but that did not work.

I'm simply trying to hide a script like:

```
< ..script  src="js/mydesktop-script.js"><../script>
```

from mobile devises - since it does not render correct but I want to show it on your regular desktop

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a remote JavaScript file conditionally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085111/how-to-include-a-remote-javascript-file-conditionally)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DetectMobileBrowsers library ([located here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)) for mobile detection. At that point, you may use a function such as the one below to have your script not be used on mobile devices (the library is kind of embedded in the code).

```
var check = false;
//if the user is on a mobile device, check = true
if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
if (!check) {
    //user is not on a mobile device
    //render your external script here
}
```

Comment: ok, to this reply above... How would i then point to my script:

Comment: @user254442 Did you even read the code? I commented exactly how to implement your script.

Comment: yes, I placed my script where you said "render your script here" and it instead blocked it from non-mobile (desktop) and allowed it on mobile. So should the true and false be reversed? Pardon, maybe Im doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use mobile detection function that's the easiest and than use it in your mydesktop-script.js to disable execution.

```
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or you can check it server side and just don't attach the js to the html.

Server side detection of mobile devices is done or in whatever language you have your app written or for example you can use varnish + esi. Virtually planty of ways to achieve that.
But as I said the easiest is to detect the device in your  script and disable part of your script based on detection result.

Comment: How do I then refer to the script: <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/mydesktop-script.js"></script>

Comment: In your mydesktop-script.js you can make make the if(detectmob()){do the desktop version of my js...}

Comment: Im sorry, Im a noob at programming. Can you place a small example. Im not sure how to correctly place the code. ty !

Comment: Sorry Im a noob, can anyone show me how to use the code properly.