# How to include a js file, on satistying the condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> ```
> <script>
>      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
>          jQuery(".tabmenu li").click(function(){
>              var current_tab = jQuery(this).attr("class");
>              var res = current_tab.replace(" active_tab",""); 
>              if(res == 'tabmenu-8')
>              {
>
>              }
>
>          });
>
>      });
> </script>
> ```

I have a script, which is written above. What I want is, I want to include a js file on satisfying the if condition. How can I do that? I tried different methods I found while searching in google, but nothing helped me.

This is the script I want to add there

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

Comment: The `<script>` you want to add is jQuery library which is required in order to run above jQuery code

Comment: @Felix I have got other library files to run this code.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham His point is that the reason you can use `jQuery(foo)` is because you **already use** jQuery - loading it again will only result in problems.

Comment: I think this question solves your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085111/how-to-include-a-remote-javascript-file-conditionally

Answer (score 3):

try this in if condition:

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.setAttribute('src','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js');
document.head.appendChild(myscript);
```

Comment: This contains a minor error: "my_awesome_script" (Line 2) is not defined since you named the variable just "myscript"

Answer (score 2):

Adding additional scripts from JavaScript is actually quite easy.
Your create a script-element and set the type and src attributes and just add it to the head (or body, it doesn't really matter)

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
newScript.setAttribute("src","http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js");
document.head.appendChild(newScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.append()`:

```
$('head').append($('<script>').attr('type', 'text/javascript').attr('src', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'));
```

---

If you've included jQuery, it's better to use **[$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)**:

```
$.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js");
```