# In an JavaScript If/else statement, how can I render a script tag based on the condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Let’s say based on a condition I want a certain JavaScript tag to be added to the HTML.

```
script1 = '<div id="render_div"></div><script src="script1"></script>';

script2 = '<div id="render_div"></div><script src="script1"></script>';


var someCondition = 0;

if (someCondition == 0) {
    //only render script1;
} else {
    //only render script2
}
```

I am thinking of using `document.write(script1);` but don't think that's the best way.

Below is the condition:

Using an API I am grabbing how many images a user folder has.  So if the count is 0 then I want to render script 2.  If the count is more than 1 then I want to render script 1.

Comment: Why not just add conditions inside script1 and script2?

Comment: @Troy not sure how i would go about that.

Comment: what kind of condition? wouldn't it be more feasible to do this server side?

Comment: Well, tell us what the condition is about.

Comment: @Troy made one slight change I forgot to put in.

Comment: Why have two scripts, and not a single easy-to-import script and call the right exposed function depending on your condition?

Comment: @Volune I am not sure.  I am still learning so just my thought process but please share what you think is the best way. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I can make a clear point in an answer, I'll try: Make a function for `condition==0` and a function for `condition!=0`. Load both function in the same script of the condition test. Call the right function in the `if..else..`. That's all, only one script, simple, no problem. Trying to load one script or another sounds like early optimization to me, which is a bad practice (unless you master web development)

Comment: @Volune Thanks.  I am trying now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid using `document.write` or can't because it is asynchronous, you could dynamically create a script tag and add it to the DOM.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
if (someCondition == 0) {
    script.src = 'script1';
} else {
    script.src = 'script2';
}
head.appendChild(script);
```

**Update for updated requirements:**

If the variables need to be HTML, you could use jQuery to append them to the DOM. jQuery will parse the HTML and load the scripts automatically.

```
if (someCondition == 0) {
    $("SOME_SELECTOR").append(script1);
} else {
    $("SOME_SELECTOR").append(script1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But looks like I might run into an issue with the <script></script> tags inside the script1 and script2 variable though.

Comment: @KPO: I've added a jQuery based solution for adding your HTML string to the DOM and loading the script.

Comment: Thanks.  Checking now.

Comment: Thanks! This worked.  I ended up using document.write.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to Question Asked

This is a nice way to do it (taken from HTML5 boilerplate)

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-{{JQUERY_VERSION}}.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

## Alternative

YepNope (http://yepnopejs.com/) offers a nice syntax for conditional loading. Usually used in combination with Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) for conditional polyfills.

Answer (score 0):

If Jquery is being used, I suggest using [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) (as suggested by this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085111/how-to-include-a-remote-javascript-file-conditionally)). Otherwise Alexander O'Mara's suggestion seems reasonable.