# How can I conditionally include a .js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my JS file:

```
function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'Angular/lang_',
    suffix: '.json'
  })

  $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en_US','es_ES', 'pt_PT','fr_FR','de_DE','ja_JP','it_IT'], {  
    'en-*':'en_US',
    'es-*':'es_ES', 
    'pt-*':'pt_PT',
    'fr-*':'fr_FR',
    'de-*':'de_DE',
    'ja-*':'ja_JP',
    'it-*':'it_IT',
    '*':'en_US'//For languages other than the above, fallback language is English.
  })    
}]
```

I have to add this file into my app.js, on some condition (when they need a translation service). So I have to separate this file and only include it when it is necessary. Is there any way to do it in angularjs, like adding `require(file)`?

Please do help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `document.write('<script src="dir/to/script.js"></script>')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a remote JavaScript file conditionally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085111/how-to-include-a-remote-javascript-file-conditionally)