# How to insert taged javascript into html dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want external js file to insert scripts into html.

This is my wrong code:

```
var logScript = `<script>console.log('ok')</script>`;
document.body.appendChild(logScript);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Some context will most likely mean we can give you a much better solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085111/how-to-include-a-remote-javascript-file-conditionally

Comment: I have advertisement codes provided by ad networks. I need external js file to insert those codes into html in some scenarios

Comment: Why do you not just include the JS file in the page with script tags?

Comment: because exernal js decides if we need to use it.

Comment: You can still do that if you include the script in your page.  You're not explaining anything that you can't do with the simple approach of `<script src="thefile.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way that I know of.

```
var logScript = document.createElement("script");
logScript.type = "text/javascript";
logScript.innerHTML = "console.log('test')";
document.body.appendChild(logScript);
```

The reason you have to do it this way, as far as I know, is because the browser thinks you are adding HTML, not a script. Another way around it is to do something like this:

```
document.body.appendChild('<script>alert("hi");</' + 'script>');
```

Here are some resources on this topic:

- https://ghinda.net/article/script-tags/
- [How to Append <script></script> in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with no need to append nor the createElement methods.
I've managed to do it in this manner:
html part:

```
<script id="jsScriptInHtml" data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

js external file:

```
let logScript = `console.log('ok')`;
document.getElementById("jsScriptInHtml").innerHTML= logScript;
```